# Need to copy a row from one spreadsheet "A" to ""B" based on a cell value in "A" and paste it in a specific row in "B" based

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy row 5 from the Sheet (“*Logg*”) in the spreadsheet "*Work Order Test.xlsm*" to another spreadsheet “*Logg_test.xlsx*”.

I want to past it on column A and the row number depends on if it is a new record or an existing record.

So basically I will find the row number based on the value on cell “B12” in the spreadsheet "*Work Order Test.xlsm*" and sheet “*work order*”.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\toreh\Documents\Logg_test.xlsx", _
    UpdateLinks:=0

Windows("Work Order Test.xlsm").Activate
   Range("B12").Select



Windows("Work Order Test.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Logg").Select
Rows("5:5").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows("Logg_test.xlsx").Activate
Set rngSearch = Range("B:B")
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(Range("B12"), LookIn:=xlValues,     LookAt:=xlPart)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Else
lastRow = rngFound.Row
End If


ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Windows("Work Order Test.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Work Order").Select
Range("A1:B1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two problems: the first is that you have Rows("5:5") instead of Range("5:5") in your code; the second one is your search value. It is the one at the cell "B12" in the active sheet of the workbook "Logg_test.xlsx", not the cell "B12" on the sheet originally active sheet on the workbook "Work Order Test.xlsm".

If you use Range on its own, this translates to

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range
```

Since you activated the workbook "Logg_test.xlsx", Range("B12") does no longer refer to the same cell.

Actually, nothing you intend to do makes it necessary to select anything and it is good practice not to do so. This helps to avoid errors like your faulty lookup value.

You could transform your code in something like the following.

```
Sub copypaste()
   Dim logg_wkb As Workbook
   Dim order_test_wkb As Workbook
   Dim test_sheet As Worksheet
   Dim logg_sheet As Worksheet
   Dim target_sheet As Worksheet
   Dim lookup_value As String
   Dim copy_rng As Range
   Dim paste_rng As Range

   Dim rngSearch As Range
   Dim rngFound As Range
   Dim pasteRow As Integer

   Set logg_wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\toreh\Documents\Logg_test.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0)
   Set order_test_wkb = Workbooks("Work Order Test.xlsm")

   Set test_sheet = order_test_wkb.ActiveSheet
   Set logg_sheet = order_test_wkb.Worksheets("Logg")
   Set target_sheet = logg_wkb.ActiveSheet

   Set copy_rng = logg_sheet.Range("5:5")

   lookup_value = test_sheet.Range("B12")
   Set rngSearch = target_sheet.Range("B:B")
   Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(lookup_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

   If IsMatch(rngFound) Then
      pasteRow = rngFound.Row
   Else
      pasteRow = Application.Intersect(rngSearch, target_sheet.UsedRange).Rows.Count + 1
   End If
   Set paste_rng = target_sheet.Range("A" & pasteRow)

   copy_rng.Copy
   paste_rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   logg_wkb.Save
   order_test_wkb.Activate
   order_test_wkb.Sheets("Work Order").Select
   Range("A1:B1").Select
End Sub

   Private Function IsMatch(MatchRng As Range) As Boolean
      IsMatch = Not (MatchRng Is Nothing)
   End Function
```

This operates in the same order as your code but only uses select in the clean up of the selection at the end, which is still necessary since Copy moves the selection.

This version is still not optimal and the several parts of the Sub should be rearranged and extracted into separate Subs and Functions to make it easier to understand. In particular, it would be a good idea to extract the logic to determine the paste range into a separate Function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see I still have a lot to learn :-). I have another question: The only spreadsheet which is fixed is Logg_test.xlsx. The other spreadsheet (where the VBA codes (macros) are stored) will not be a fixed file name, so how can I refer to that file when the name is not always the same.

Comment: How to get the reference to the other workbook (I guess this is "Work Order Test.xlsm" in your code.) depends in which of three cases you are.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the other workbook is active when the macro is called, i.e. by calling it via a button in this workbook, you can just assign the ActiveWorkbook to the corresponding variable. If it is only the directory that is different and the workbook is open, the code above works. (Your code actually assumes that the workbook is open.) Otherwise, you have to get the information somehow in, i.e. writing it in a specified field and reading the filename from there.